# Prove convexity (product of two functions)

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Is there a way to prove convexity of
$$ f\left(\frac{x^{\mathsf T}\sigma}{\sqrt{x^{\mathsf T}\Sigma x }}\right)\sqrt{x^{\mathsf T}\Sigma x}$$
where $\sigma$ is a vector, $\Sigma$ is positive definite, $f$ is positive with $\frac{df}{dz}>0$?

PS: Finding the Hessian does not seem to work.

Comment: What is $df/dz$? Is $\sigma$ nonnegative? A sufficient condition is that $t f(x^T \sigma /t)$ is increasing in $t$ for each $x$

Comment: Thank you for your response! $df/dz$ is the derivative of $f$ wrt its argument (independent variable); $\sigma$ is just a vector. Where does your sufficient condition follow from?

Comment: The condition is from replacing $\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x}$ with $y$, and then taking the minimum over $y$ under the convex constraint $\sqrt{x^T \Sigma x} \leq y$. Partial minimization over $y$ gives the result. I can work it out as an answer if it's not clear and this condition works for you.

Comment: That's the issue: it's far from obvious that $tf(x^T\sigma/t)$ is increasing in $t$. The derivative $f-f'\frac{x^T\sigma}{t}$ is not obviously positive.

Comment: The function in @LinAlg's sufficient condition looks like a perspective function.  Check out Section 24.6 from Bauschke & Combettes' book, volume 2. If $f$ is convex, then the perspective of $f$ is positively homogeneous and sublinear.